# Python, how to insert a list into column of table in given order

Tags: python, mysql

My table has 3 columns: ID, Author and In_order. I am reading in a file and a line contains a list of authors separated by a comma. What I am trying to achieve is inserting the names of the authors into the author column with its correct ID in the ID field and then the position in which it appears in the list (which will always be in order). What I want in the end is my table looking like this:

```
ID    Author    In_order
1     Author1    1
1     Author2    2
1     Author3    3
2     Author1    1
2     Author2    2
3     Author1    1
3     Author2    2
```

I have used the enumerate function to give each author a position in the list.

Here is the code relevant to this question.

```
author_list = line.split(",")

        for In_order, author in enumerate(author_list, start=1):
            In_order = In_order
            author = author

db1.execute('''INSERT INTO authors(
                    ID, AUTHOR, In_order) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)''',
                    (ID, author, In_order))
```

I wasn't sure what exactly to store in both the In_order and author variables. 
The code runs but only the last author on the list is inserted into the table along with its corresponding ID and its correct position on the list. Ie.:

```
ID    Author    In_order
1     Author3    3
2     Author2    2
3     Author2    2
```

Any advice would be appreciated I am new to both python and mysql!

Comment: your insert is "outdented" from the `for` loop, so the `db1` stuff runs AFTER the loop completes, which means you'll only ever get the last item iterated by the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You want the `.execute` statement to be in the loop.

```
    for In_order, author in enumerate(author_list, start=1):
        In_order = In_order
        author = author

        db1.execute('''INSERT INTO authors(
                           ID, AUTHOR, In_order) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)''',
                           (ID, author, In_order))
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things wrong. First in MySQL you do not need to store the order, you store the DATA that you want to sort by later. Maybe you're mis-labeling this In_order field. Maybe the data actually is something else.

Second the author ID should be unique, I see yours as repeating.

Comment: I think I can see where you are coming from.. In_order in this case is just a variable and I want to store the positions of each author in it. And in regards to a unique key, I have a composite primary key wherein the combination of the the ID and the In_order value(position) of the author in the list is the unique therefore it should still allow me to repeat the ID in the ID column. Does that make slightly more sense or am I way off the mark? Thanks for any feedback @dlite922

Comment: I think you want the execute function to be inside the for loop scope like @bernie said because outside the for loop the variables ID, author and In_order do not make sense (technical term: out of scope)